# A production ready server to serve django on win32

Tags: python, windows, django

I'd like to serve django application on windows XP/Vista.
The application is an at hoc web interface to a windows program so it won't be put under heavy load (around 100 requests per second).

Do you know any small servers that can be easily deployed on windows to serve a django app? (IIS is not an option as the app should work on all versions of windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org) includes a good server. [Here](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/25/serving-django-cherrypy/)'s how you set it up to work with django and some benchmarks.

[twisted.web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb) has [wsgi](http://wsgi.org) support and that could be used to run your django application. [Here](http://blog.dreid.org/2009/03/twisted-django-it-wont-burn-down-your.html)'s how you do it.

In fact any [wsgi](http://wsgi.org) server will do. Here's one more example, this time using [spawning](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning):

```
$ spawn --factory=spawning.django_factory.config_factory mysite.settings
```

And for using [paste](http://pythonpaste.org/), the info is gathered [here](http://pythonpaste.org/djangopaste/).

Of course, you could use apache with [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). It would be just another wsgi server. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) are the setup instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give Apache a go, check out [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to see if it'll work for you. You can do a lightweight (read: no installation) "installation." Of course, you'll also want to install [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) to run Django. [This](http://jyotirmaya.blogspot.com/2008/11/xampp-python-django.html) post may help you set everything up. (Note: I have not used python/Django with XAMPP myself.)

Edit: Before someone points this out, XAMPP is not generally a production-ready tool. It's simply a useful way to see whether Apache will work for you. Also, I saw that you're using SQLite after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Apache ?

Nokia have developed a scaled down version of apache to run on their mobile phones. It supports python.

http://research.nokia.com/research/projects/mobile-web-server/

Also do you need anything else such as database support etc?

Comment: I though that Apache is a bit to heavy but i will check that link out. Thank you. Regarding the db support i will use sqlight.

Comment: Please bear in mind this web server will run off a mobile phone. It's designed not to be heavy.

Comment: I just love the fact that I can run Apache on my phone at all. It's awesome!